# How to edit hidden character in String

Tags: r, string, view, rstudio

The appearance of "textparcali" in RStudio Source Editor was as follows.

[image: Before running the code]

In textparcali (tbl_df), I ran the following code to delete single strings.

```
textparcali$word<-gsub("\\W*\\b\\w\\b\\W*",'', textparcali$word)
```

But the deletion was interesting. You can see the picture below. Please note lines 67 and 50.

[image: After running the code]

Everything was fine for line 50 and lines like that. However, this was not the case for line 67 (and I think there are others like it).
I focused on one line(67) to understand why you deleted it wrong. I've already seen what it says on this line in the editor. But I also wanted to look at the console. I wrote the following code to the console.

```
textparcali$word[67]
```

The word on line 67 looks different in the console. The value that doesn't appear when you make a copy paste but surprisingly appears on the console:

[image]

The reason I put it as a picture is because this character disappears after the copy-paste command. 
You can download the file containing this character from the link below. However, you should open it with Notepad ++.
[Character.txt](http://www.erkanhoca.com/?page_id=48)

Gsub did his job right. How is that possible? What's the name of this character? When I try to write code that destroys this character, the " sign changes and does not delete.

[image]

`textparcali$word<-gsub('[[:punct:]]+',' ',textparcali$word)` command also does not work.

What is the explanation of my experience? I do not know. Is there a way to destroy this character? What caused this? I ve asked a lot.

Thank you all.
(I apologize for the bad scribbles in the pictures.)

Comment: You can always(and should) just copy and paste the output to the question instead of pictures. Since focus is on lines 67, could be best to filter and only add that. Unless of course this is specific to `View`.

Comment: I don't think it's only line 67. Many more lines may have this problem. Words containing this character are affected.

Comment: Yes, the main point really is that images are a less desired way to provide code/data for several reasons. Do you get this issue when you don't use `View`? What is the encoding of the data?

Comment: The word that appeared after the `View` command was in the correct format. Data is stored in the database in UTF-8 format. I get this data with the following commands. `dbSendQuery(connection,"SET NAMES 'latin5' COLLATE 'latin5_turkish_ci'") `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the surprise character.

```
Above Right, Combining Dot  &#x0358;    ͘
```

The following is the code required to eliminate this character.

> c<-"surprise character"
>   c
>   [1] "\u0358"

```
textparcali$word<-gsub("\u0358","",textparcali$word,ignore.case = FALSE)
textparcali$word<-gsub("\u307","",textparcali$word,ignore.case = FALSE)
```

**Code 307 did the job for me. However, you should determine what the actual code is. If not, your character code may be incorrect.**

More detailed information can be found in the links below.

https://gist.github.com/ngs/2782436
https://www.charbase.com/0358-unicode-combining-dot-above-right

Thanks a lot!